# How can I fix this fountain and prevent it from happening again?

Tags: backyard

I bought a [fountain](https://serenityhealth.com/sunnydaze-lovers-umbrella-solar-with-battery-backup-outdoor-water-fountain-led-lights-43-inch-tall-includes-battery-pack/) recently and since it's been below freezing I put it outside empty. Well, it fell over in the first high wind day. Now the statue part has cracked off the base, and part of the bit that attaches them is cracked in half.

I assume I should try to fix it with an epoxy of some kind?

And how do I prevent it from cracking again if it falls over?

Do I need to bury the base of it?

Wait to put it outside until it's consistently above freezing at night and put water in it?

Comment: "how do I prevent it from cracking again if it falls over?" You can't, unless you wrap it in soft padding, which would make it unusable. I don't think the freezing has anything to do with the problem because I don't think the weight of the water is enough to hold it down in another similar wind event. I think you need to *prevent* it from falling over regardless of the temp./water.

Comment: Is there enough space in the middle (where I'm guessing there's some pipes and/or wiring) to fit a piece of rebar? If so you could drive the rebar 2 or 3 feet into the ground, leaving 1 or 2 feet exposed and then lift the fountain and place it over the rebar.

Answer (score 2):

**Tie it down.**

[image: fountain with red cable tying down]

Here is your fountain.  You can tie it down across the white base which I assume is attached to the plastic fountain bowl and statue.  You could use a nylon or poly rope of some color you thought was unobstrusive.

You could tie the rope to stakes and then hammer the stakes all the way into the ground then put the mulch back on top.  That would make sure rope is tight.  I show 2 ropes but you could use 4.

Comment: The white part is not part of the fountain, more's the pity

Comment: Is the white part also plastic or resin?  Since you have out the epoxy for your repair on the upper part you could glue the fountain down to the base, maybe with dowels in between for a better attachment.

Comment: No no, the white part is just in that picture, there is no white part in the shipped fountain.

Comment: You could do the same procedure with the gray fountain and wrap cords around base.  Or attach one or two stakes to the bottom of the foundation underneath the base and drive it into the ground.  OR if fountain interior is hollow (I suspect so if it blew over) cut a hole and lower the whole thing onto a long stake firmly in the ground.